# Turborepo - library consuming another library - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, turborepo

Reproduction app: https://github.com/uriklar/turborepo-lib-dep-lib-repro

I'm using Turborepo's basic example (nextjs app + ui library)

I want to add an additional ui library and have my ui library depend on it.

```
// packages/ui/Button.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { Button as AnotherButton} from "anotherui"
export const Button = () => {
  return <><button>Boop</button><AnotherButton/></>;
};
```

I created the `anotherui` library inside the packages directory and added it as a dependency of `ui` like so:

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "./index.tsx",
  "types": "./index.tsx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "anotherui": "workspace:*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "tsconfig": "workspace:*",
    "config": "workspace:*",
    "typescript": "^4.5.3"
  }
}
```

When I try to build the `web` app (that consumes `Button` from `ui`) I'm getting the following error:

```
web:build: Failed to compile.
web:build: 
web:build: ../../packages/anotherui/Button.tsx
web:build: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:9)
web:build: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
web:build: | import * as React from "react";
web:build: | export const Button = () => {
web:build: >   return <button>Boop</button>;
web:build: | };
web:build: | 
web:build: 
web:build: Import trace for requested module:
web:build: ../../packages/anotherui/index.tsx
web:build: ../../packages/ui/Button.tsx
web:build: ../../packages/ui/index.tsx
web:build: ./pages/index.tsx
web:build:
```

My question is:
Is it possible to have one library depend on another library from the same monorepo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Found the solution. It was actually related to Next.js.
Turborepo already uses a module called "next-transpile-modules" and in my `next.config.js` file I already had this line:

```
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["ui"]);
```

So I just added `"anotherui"` to the array and it worked

Answer (score 13):

## Next.js 13

Just add this line and include any modules you want to be compiled by the Next Compiler in your `next.config.mjs`:

```js
/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
const config = {
  // ...
  + transpilePackages: ['ui']
};
```

[Next Module Transpilation Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#module-transpilation)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the shared package in your child repo, that will solve your issue.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  transpilePackages: ["@repo/ui"],
};
```